# RSpec with jruby- NoMethodError: undefined method `read_all' for nil:NilClass when using --drb with spork

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec2, rspec-rails, spork, drb

Afer adding --drb to the .rspec file, I am getting the following error with spork running. I am using jruby-1.6.7 on mac

```
$ jruby -S rspec
NoMethodError: undefined method `read_all' for nil:NilClass
  method_missing at /Users/larry/.rvm/rubies/jruby-1.6.7/lib/ruby/1.9/drb/drb.rb:1099
             run at /Users/larry/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.7@entercamp/gems/rspec-core-2.8.0/lib/rspec/core/drb_command_line.rb:19
    run_over_drb at /Users/larry/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.7@entercamp/gems/rspec-core-2.8.0/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:76
             run at /Users/larry/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.7@entercamp/gems/rspec-core-2.8.0/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:63
         autorun at /Users/larry/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.7@entercamp/gems/rspec-core-2.8.0/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:10
```

following are the rspec gems version I am using:

```
rspec (2.8.0)
rspec-core (2.8.0)
rspec-expectations (2.8.0)
rspec-mocks (2.8.0)
rspec-rails (2.8.1)
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a jruby-1.9 bug: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RUBY-9129